# Swift 3 json parsing

Tags: json, swift3

I am running into troubles updating my app as Alamofire and SwiftyJSON are not yet supporting Swift 3. I have a url that would return me json as follows:

```
{
    "products": [
        {
            "body_html":"",
            "created_at":"2016-03-02T13:56:18+03:00",
            "id":489759251,
            "handle":"product",
            "options":[
                {
                    "id":627488838,
                    "product_id":489759251,
                    "name":"Title",
                    "position":1,
                    "values":[
                        "Default Title"
                    ]
                }
            ],

        },

        {
            "body_html":"",
            "created_at":"2016-03-08T05:17:55+03:00",
            "id":530420915,
            "handle":"product-2",
            "options":[
                {
                    "id":6319359750,
                    "product_id":530420915,
                    "name":"Title",
                    "position":1,
                    "values":[
                        "Default Title"
                    ]
                }
            ],

        },
    ]
}
```

I need to be able to parse that json and list all returned products and be able to read any specific attribute and sub options of each.

I checked some other questions here and found several solutions and was able to get the json data and printed it as above. But, I couldn't parse it.

```
let shopUrl = "https://\(apiKey):\(password)@\(hostname)" + "/admin/products.json"

let url = URL(string: shopUrl)
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print(error)
    } else {
        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! [String:Any]
            print(json)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}).resume()
```

Any help?

Comment: That's not JSON, that's the output of a `print` line representing the result of the deserialization.

Comment: yes, that's right. I thought providing the print output will make it easier to provide me help

Comment: I know it doesn't help answering your question but Alamofire4.0 does have Swift 3 support. SwiftyJSON doesn't have any Swift 3 support apart from a branch for one of the early betas..

Comment: @donnywals exactly, that's why I am stuck here :(

Comment: Better post the raw JSON string.

Comment: What part are you stuck at exactly? Does the serialisation work? And the `print(json)` line outputs that snippet you showed first?

Comment: here is the json out put

Comment: @donnywals yes, I am able to print that output but can't loop over it to list it in table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To loop over all of the products you need to extract and cast it to the correct type. In this case an array of `[String: Any]`.

I extracted the relevant bit of code and cleaned it up a bit to make this answer more readable.

```
guard let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: Any],
    let products = json["products"] as? [[String: Any]]
    else { return }

for product in products {
    guard let id = product["id"] as? Int,
        let options = product["options"] as? [[String: Any]]
        else { return }

    print(id)
    print(options)
}
```

Comment: is it possible to get the count of products?

Comment: Thank you very much donnywals

Answer (score 0):

This parses the JSON, the root object is a dictionary, the objects for `products` and `options` are arrays. One value respectively is printed as an example.

```
if let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:data, options: []) as? [String:Any] {
  print(jsonObject)
  if let products = jsonObject["products"] as? [[String:Any]] {
    for aProduct in products {
      print(aProduct["created_at"])
      if let options = aProduct["options"] as? [[String:Any]] {
        for option in options {
          print(option["product_id"])
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd advice to use `guard` instead of all these `if let` constructions. The nesting will quickly lead to the infamous pyramid of doom..