# parsing json in swift 3

Tags: json, swift

I have a problem with JSON file parsing how correctly parse it? I'm new for Swift and try parse JSO but got empty. Actually list is not empty, Debugger Image :

[image: debugger show]
The issue is how can I parse json
JSON:

```
 {
    "list" : { 
    "meta" : { 
    "type" : "resource-list",
    "start" : 0,
    "count" : 188
    },
    "resources" : [ 
    {
    "resource" : { 
    "classname" : "Quote",
    "fields" : { 
    "name" : "USD/KRW",
    "price" : "1147.310059",
    "symbol" : "KRW=X",
    "ts" : "1489185046",
    "type" : "currency",
    "utctime" : "2017-03-10T22:30:46+0000",
    "volume" : "0"
    }
    }
    }
    ,
    {
    "resource" : { 
    "classname" : "Quote",
    "fields" : { 
    "name" : "SILVER 1 OZ 999 NY",
    "price" : "0.058634",
    "symbol" : "XAG=X",
    "ts" : "1489325701",
    "type" : "currency",
    "utctime" : "2017-03-12T13:35:01+0000",
    "volume" : "36"
    }
    }
    }
```

Swift Code:

```
    let Url = NSURL(string: stockUrl)
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: Url! as URL)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){ data, response, error in

        if error != nil
        {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }


do {
     if let data = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as?  [String: AnyObject]{

       let list = data["list"] as? [[String: Any]] ?? []
       print(list)

        }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }   
    }
    task.resume()

    }
```

Comment: lsabekov show your code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift 3 json parsing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39609726/swift-3-json-parsing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to parse it. It's already a dictionary. You can access the value with key directly

Comment: Well, that's what I think "deserialize" means.